# Edit String value on file using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a manifest file with the following information:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Runtime (2.7)
Bundle-SymbolicName: Runtime;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.5.qualifier
```

I need to update it through bash commands. Is it possible to do it using sed command.
I need to update the bundle-version to be like these one:

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.6.qualifier
```

Right now I'm able to do it this way:

```
sed -i '' "s/Bundle-Version: 1.0.5.qualifier/Bundle-Version: 1.0.6.qualifier/g" MANIFEST.MF
```

but I want to find a way to not replace the entire line and just replace the version.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial. What problem are you having with it? Please show your attempted code.

Comment: Right now I'm able to do it this way:    sed -i '' "s/Bundle-Version: 1.0.5.qualifier/Bundle-Version: 1.0.6.qualifier/g" MANIFEST.MF , but I want to find a way to not replace the entire line and just replace the version.

Comment: `s/1\.0\.5/1.0.6/` will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to replace the whole line, you can do:

```
s/1\.0\.5\.qualifier/1.0.6.qualifier/
```

to just replace that part of the line. However, this will replace that string on any line, not just the `Bundle-Version` line. You can use an address expression to limit it:

```
/^Bundle-Version:/s/1\.0\.5/1.0.6/
```

There's no need to use the `g` modifier, since the version number only needs to be replaced once on the line.

Comment: thanks!! I was able to do it this way